# PowerBI DAX Filtering by MIN/MAX Date from Slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns

I have a table named 'Master Query' that holds a column called 'RegisterDate'. My PowerBI dashboard has Date Slicer that allows the user to control the data shown on a Matrix table. I am trying to create a new summarised table by filtering the MIN and MAX Date ranges that the user has chosen in the slicer.

I have tried this DAX code below but it seems the dates are not being picked up as all rows are returning rather than only summarising the rows within the desired date range:

```
HE KPI Card = 
VAR _MinDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Master Query'[RegisterDate]),ALLSELECTED('Master Query'[RegisterDate]))
VAR _MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Master Query'[RegisterDate]),ALLSELECTED('Master Query'[RegisterDate]))
RETURN
CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE('Master Query',Students[ID],'KPItarget'[Description],"Mark1",SUM('Master Query'[Mark1]),"Mark2",SUM('Master Query'[Mark2]),"AuthCount",SUM('Master  Query'[AuthorisedCount])),FILTER('Master Query','Master Query'[RegisterDate] >= _MinDate &&  'Master Query'[RegisterDate] <= _MaxDate))
```

Main part of DAX code:

```
HE KPI Card = 
VAR _MinDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Master Query'[RegisterDate]),ALLSELECTED('Master Query'[RegisterDate]))
VAR _MaxDate = CALCULATE(MAX('Master Query'[RegisterDate]),ALLSELECTED('Master Query'[RegisterDate]))
RETURN
FILTER('Master Query','Master Query'[RegisterDate] >= _MinDate &&  'Master Query'[RegisterDate] <= _MaxDate))
```

How would I go about doing this? I am unsure why my DAX is not working...perhaps there is a better way of doing it within PowerBI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculated Table are "calculated" once at refresh time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables

> Calculated tables are recalculated if any of the tables they pull data
> from are refreshed or updated, unless the table uses data from a table
> that uses DirectQuery

If you want to only show summarized data then a better idea is to create new measures with 0/1 output. Put everything that you need to table visualization -> columns and measures + add to filter pane this new measure to show only 1 (based on your date condition).

If this is not the case, then describe in detail what do you want to achieve.

Comment: But I don't want to hard code a date range - I want the date range to be the users slicers selection. So when I have 0/1 output by doing a IF condition, how would I reference those dates in that condition...so if Register is between this and this then 1 otherwise 0...

Comment: But it does seem like feasible solution if the date ranges can be dynamic

Comment: VAR _MinDate = CALCULATE(MIN('Master Query'[RegisterDate].[Date]),ALLSELECTED('Master Query'[RegisterDate].[Date]))...I don't this works as always return the minimum out of all dates...not what is selected by the user in the slicer

Comment: We do not have to enter the range rigidly (hardcoding). We can get it from the selector. We can rely on the SELECTEDVALUE function. You can edit your question and provide source data + selector + expected output.